# How to create a display format for a number divided by 1000?

Tags: c#, format, devexpress, display

i have decimals and want to display them as "thousand €" but without any positions after the decimal point.
For instance 56000.45 should be displayed as 56 T €.
I have tried several ways and read about using the "," for division, and have tried adding it to this expression: {0:N0} T € but without success.
Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: without devexpress I would use ```string.Format("Value is {0} T€",(int) (X/1000.0));```. you might consider rounding (up)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
decimal currency = (56000.45 - (decimal) 56000.45 % 1000) /1000;
```

d will now equal 56.00, you can use

```
Math.Round(currency)
```

to get the value 56